# How to avoid stale state in React functional component

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a game in React which also uses the Google Firestore in order to keep track of game data.

In the game, the user will hit "Start" and be connected to a Google Firebase collection, which starts listening for changes to the database. When something in the database changes, the React component state will change.

The problem I am having is that is seems that the version of `state` my listener's callback function uses is out of date. The listener is set in response to the player hitting the start button, and the component's `state` at that time seems to be cached.

The problematic component looks like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Counter() {
  const [state, setFullState] = useState({
    count: 0,
    clicks: 0,
    started: false
  });

  const setState = update => {
    setFullState(prevState => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        ...update
      };
    });
  };

  const handleStart = () => {
    const increment = () => {
      const { clicks } = state;
      setState({ clicks: clicks + 1 });
    };
    setState({
      started: true
    });
    document.addEventListener("click", increment);
  };

  const { clicks, count, started } = state;

  if (!started) {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleStart}>START</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Hooks</h2>
      <p>Count: {count}</p>
      <p>Clicks: {clicks}</p>
      <p>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setState({ count: count + 1 });
          }}
        >
          More
        </button>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Counter;
```

I created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-smoke-4ziwu) to demonstrate the problem. When you click on the button, the "Clicks" number does not increase.

What is a good way to make a function reference the component's `state` at the time the function is *called*, not at the time the function is *created*?

Comment: It is not clear what you want. You told about Google Firebase but gave an example with the `click` listener. What I can tell you about your example is that you must to add listeners only in `useEffect` hooks, because you have to unsubscribe from events when you component unmounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `useRef` you can keep a snapshot of the state visible in the now stale `increment` callback, and keep it in sync.

```
const currentState = React.useRef(state)
currentState.current = state
```

then

```
  const handleStart = () => {
    const increment = () => {
      const { clicks } = currentState.current;
      setState({ clicks: clicks + 1 });
    };
    setState({
      started: true
    });
    document.addEventListener("click", increment);
  };
```

This should answer your question, but your problem can be solved in a better way than this.

Comment: `setState` also have to be reffed, otherwise it won't work

Comment: Just for a coincidence, I don't think is going to matter in this specific case: setFullState function is stable, so doesn't matter if setState isn't. But yeah, if setState will do something else in the future, like reading state as well, is not going to work

Comment: right, `setFullState` is stable, so instead of refs, it can be done with `setFullState(state => ({...state, clicks: state.clicks+ 1}))`

Comment: @Federkun I got it working using this solution but can you give any indication of what would be the "better way" to solve it?

Comment: Depends on which problem you really need to solve. You can use `useReducer` and dispatch action in your listener. Or just ```    document.addEventListener("click", () => {
      setFullState((currentState) => ({
        ...currentState,
        clicks: currentState.clicks + 1
      }))
    });```, save the last increment callback into a ref, and invoke that, etc.